# SonarQube saying me "remove this use of constructor "Scanner(InputStream)"

Tags: java, sonarqube

What should i use instead of Scanner so that SonarQube will not complain?

```
final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: I think SQ is referring to the 'final' keyword. Why is Scanner final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the following [rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1943) in SonarQube:

> **Classes and methods that rely on the default system encoding should not be used**
>
> Using classes and methods that rely on the default system encoding can result in code that works fine in its "home" environment. But that code may break for customers who use different encodings in ways that are extremely difficult to diagnose and nearly, if not completely, impossible to reproduce when it's time to fix them.

To fix it, you can use the scanner with a defined encoding type:

```
/**
 * Constructs a new <code>Scanner</code> that produces values scanned
 * from the specified input stream. Bytes from the stream are converted
 * into characters using the specified charset.
 *
 * @param  source An input stream to be scanned
 * @param charsetName The encoding type used to convert bytes from the
 *        stream into characters to be scanned
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the specified character set
 *         does not exist
 */
public Scanner(InputStream source, String charsetName) {
    this(makeReadable(Objects.requireNonNull(source, "source"), toCharset(charsetName)),
         WHITESPACE_PATTERN);
}
```